# can I share a database between Django 1.11 and Django 2.x?

Tags: django

Can Django 1.x and 2.x share the same database, or does 2.x make changes to the database that would break 1.x?

My app currently runs on on Python 3.6 + Django 1.11.   I need to upgrade to Django 2.x.

What I'd like to do is run two apps side-by-side:  so "www.example.com" is my production site, running Django 1.11.   I'd like to run a parallel site for trusted users at "beta.example.com" which would be the same site, but implemented with Django 2.x.   I want these two sites to share the same (Postgres) database so that

- work done in the beta site is "real" and will persist
- if something can't be done in the beta site, i can tell a user to use the existing production site
- I can promote my beta site to production by changing DNS entries.

(And my next question will be "Can Django 1.x and 3.x share the same Postgres database?")

Answer (score 1):

Yes, simply upgrading Django 1.11 to Django 2.0 (or 3.0) will pose no problem, aside from possible migrations in the core/contrib models you're using, `auth` being the most probable one. Happily, though, [the last migrations in `auth`](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/contrib/auth/migrations) seem to have been just emlengthening fields, which probably doesn't change things too much in usual use cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can share the same database with two Django instances, even different software, as long as you don't change the tables already in use. If your beta application is going to use different class names(which are tables names in database) then you are good
Although in practice it is a really bad idea. I would suggest you use Heroku for development in Django. It is free, easy and fast to set up and you can test your application on the URL they provide. Once happy you can then migrate your site,
Read this for setting up
https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/working-with-django